# R Sqldf Query with Like Operator and Sprintf

Tags: r, sqldf

I am attempting to query for all rows in a df where the *date* column, formatted as YYYYMMDD, contains the given year.

Here is my current query:

```
county_rows <- sqldf(sprintf("select * from county_rows where 'date' LIKE '%s%%'", year))
```

Does anyone see what I am doing wrong? I am currently not getting back any results. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't put the variable name as a string, i.e.

```
sqldf::sqldf(sprintf("select * from county_rows where date LIKE '%s%%'", year))
```

will work for you.

Comment: Normally one would write this as: `library(sqldf); fn$sqldf("select * from country_rows where date like '$year' ")`   Add the `verbose=TRUE` argument to `sqldf` if you want to see the final SQL used.